# What is difference between '(blank)where' and 'where' in Mysql update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

```
private function update($fields)
    {
      $query = 'UPDATE`'.$this->table.'`SET';
      foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $query .= '`' . $key . '` = :'. $key . ',';
      }
      $query = rtrim($query, ',');
      $query .= ' WHERE `'. $this->primaryKey . '` = :primaryKey';
      $fields['primaryKey'] = $fields['id'];

      $fields = $this->processDates($fields);

      $this->query($query,$fields);
    }
```

I want to make the update method and these codes work. but when I change

```
$query .= ' WHERE `'. $this->primaryKey . '` = :primaryKey';
```

into

```
$query .= 'WHERE `'. $this->primaryKey . '` = :primaryKey';
```

, then it doesn't work. I guess the only difference is blank in front of WHERE.

I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Print you query text and see how can sql understand something like `UPDATE table SET a = 42WHERE id = 1`.

Comment: "I really don't understand why it doesn't work"...because if you don't leave a gap between the different parts of the SQL then it isn't valid SQL, the SQL compiler can't understand it. It can't distinguish the preceding value from the WHERE clause. It's unclear why you thought it would be helpful to remove the space in the first place - what was your motivation? And as u_mulder says, did you take a look at the appearance of the final query after you made your change?

Comment: When in doubt (and writing non-meticulous sloppy code), *always* pad each end of sql concatenations with spaces. The db execution doesn't care if you have multiple spaces (or even tabs)... so long as you have some sort of whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

You are appending where clause to update query so without blank your update query is:

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName = :placeholderWHERE primaryKey = :primaryKey;
```

With the blank:

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName = :placeholder WHERE primaryKey = :primaryKey;
```

That is the difference.

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally understand.